# How to distribute Vusers among actions in Load Runner? and find concurrent users doing same action

Tags: loadrunner

In the HP load-runner controller , i can give the number of Vusers that needs to execute a scenario . if the scenario has multiple action , i set weighted percentage for each action to be executed randomly. But is there any possible way to find the transaction time for the action and during that transaction how many other users were doing the same action? and is there any way to restrict the number of user who can do the same action concurrently ?

Comment: Sorry ??  I am trying to learn things on my own

Comment: There is a downloadable tutorial available at no charge.  Also, print the books and read them

Comment: Now found the way , thanks for your Blabla